# SpreadsheetGear - Save Specific Workbook Sheet to CSV

Tags: export-to-csv, spreadsheetgear

I am opening an existing Excel file using SpreadsheetGear, using the following code:

SpreadsheetGear.IWorkbook xlBook = SpreadsheetGear.Factory.GetWorkbook(fileName, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
            xlBook.SaveAs(fileNameCSV, SpreadsheetGear.FileFormat.CSV);

This works, but the saved CSV file contains the wrong sheet.

Can anyone help with a code snippet on how to open an Excel file in SpreadsheetGear, then save only a SPECIFIC sheet to a CSV file.

Please note I am working with SpreadsheetGear and want a solution for that library. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [IWorksheet](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.8.0/#SpreadsheetGear2017~SpreadsheetGear.IWorksheet_members.html) interface includes a [SaveAs](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.8.0/#SpreadsheetGear2017~SpreadsheetGear.IWorksheet~SaveAs.html)(...) method for just this purpose:

```
using SpreadsheetGear;
using System.Globalization;
...

IWorkbook xlBook = Factory.GetWorkbook(fileName, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture); 
xlBook.Worksheets["My Sheet"].SaveAs(fileNameCSV, FileFormat.CSV);
```

I'll also mention that there is also an IRange.[SaveAs](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.8.0/#SpreadsheetGear2017~SpreadsheetGear.IRange~SaveAs.html)(...) method if you want to save just a particular range to CSV / UnicodeText (tab-delimited).

Comment: Thanks Tim this is perfect